# Best way to do database-driven styles in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

This is a little bit of a subjective question but I hope SO can help.

I'm making a ReactJS app and I need to customize certain parts of the style (the color scheme mostly) based on a user's settings in a database.  The color palette is spread out over a lot of the style sheet so I'd like to avoid setting all those colors by hand in the `render()` method.

One option is to server-side render the full css file on every request. Would something like SASS be able to do this in real time? I know most preprocessors are designed for compile-time use.

Another option would be to embed the styling in a JavaScript module with something like [react-style](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-style).  Each components "stylesheet" could actually become a function that takes some preferences and returns styles.  This strategy has some downsides (as described [here](http://jamesknelson.com/why-you-shouldnt-style-with-javascript/)) plus the extra inconvenience of having to pas a "styleSettings" prop down to EVERY component so it could know how to request its styles.

Alternatively I could just have a single global or page-wide style sheet so I have to deal with fewer props, but I like the modularity of each component getting its own style.

Are there any other options I'm missing here? Is there a best practice for doing this type of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) does most of what I wanted to do pretty easily.  As a bonus, it has built in support for global themes, so I don't have to think about theme setting in my component props.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, but I accomplished something similar using a theme-provider HoC.

```
class ThemeProvider extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // fetch required data if you don't already have it

    // create a <style> node
    this.styleTag = document.createElement('style')
    this.styleTag.type = 'text/css'

    document.head.appendChild(this.styleTag)
  }

  /* update the styles if the data source has changed */
  componentDidUpdate ({ styles: prevStyles }, prevState) {
    const { styles: currentStyles } = this.props

    if (!isEqual(currentStyles, prevStyles)) {
      // generate the css ex
      const css = `
        .some_selector {
          color: ${currentStyles.color}
        }
      `

      // update the <style> node
      this.styleTag.textContent = css
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props 
    return children
  }
}
```

you would use it like

```
<ThemeProvider>
  <RootComponent/>
</ThemeProvider>
```

**pros**

- globally apply CSS from one location
- fairly *cheap* in terms of reconciliation

**cons**

- a little bit of "magic" involved (i.e. where are these styles coming from?)
- component is mounted before styles are applied - i.e. after render... meaning the first load might have styles "flash" in
- slightly destructive - `.some_selector { color: ... }` would override `hover`, etc effects... nothing you can't easily fix, though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you either intend to or already have made use of inline styles within your React components. I myself use inline styles from time to time even if this is frowned upon by the vox populi of the React community. Sometimes inline styles are actually the most elegant solution to a React problem, however, in this situation I propose that you stick with using class names so you can leave the application of color to your stylesheet. You would still want to use a CSS preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) to apply the different color themes based on the user's settings, which is what I am currently doing on my project. So you would apply classes such as: color-primary, color-secondary, color-accent to your DOM content and those classes would have their colors set via the user data.